# Getting error to create sitemaps in a separate directory for each store view

Tags: multistore, sitemaps, magento-1.9.2.1

While I'm trying to create the sitemaps in separate directories, it lets me create the first one only and for the second one gives me error:
`Path "/sitemap/en/en_sitemap.xml" is not available and cannot be used.` My wish was below structure

```
/sitemap/nl/sitemap.xml
/sitemap/en/en_sitemap.xml
```

I have checked the ownership and permissions, what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with file naming. It seems it has to be `sitemap.xml`, and after renaming the `en_sitemap.xml` it worked.